# Copying Jar files into single zip file

Tags: unix, gzip, jar

I am trying to compress the hundreds of jar files into a single zip file that can be transferred to a different location. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are very similar to zip archives therefore combining them into one archive will not save a lot of space. However if you really want to make one zip archive then one of the simplest solution would be to execute for loop on all jar files:

```
for f in *.jar; do
 zip archive.zip "$f"
done
```

If you want to use gzip, then:

```
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz *.jar
```